# Rotating points around pivot in 3D space

Tags: unity-game-engine, math

I'm trying to rotate points around a pivot in 3D space so that each circle is facing the previous circle so that when connected they form a tube shape. I'm struggling with the correct way to move the points in Unity.

This is how they look before rotation:
[image]

The missing piece is in the `RotatePointAroundPivot` function. I've tried

```
var newVector = Quaternion.Euler(velocity) * originalVector;
// this seems to be wrong as velocity is in Unity distance units, and it takes degrees, which I'm not sure how to calculate from a vector
```

```
// this doesn't work either, looks like the same reason, it takes degrees, which I don't know how to calculate
var newVector = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationDegrees, pivot) * originalVector;
```

I looked at [this thread](https://answers.unity.com/questions/532297/rotate-a-vector-around-a-certain-point.html) but this solution assumes you already have the correct angle calculated. I don't know how to turn my velocity into an angle.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CircleDrawing : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 RotatePointAroundPivot(Vector3 point, Vector3 pivot, Vector3 velocity)
    {
        var originalVector = point - pivot;

        var newVector = ???; // what goes here to create the newVector? Need to take velocity and turn it into an angle to alter originalVector

        return newVector + pivot;
    }

    void DrawCircle(Vector3 center, Vector3 velocity)
    {
        Color color = Random.ColorHSV();

        var circleSteps = 10;
        var circleRadius = 5;

        for (int i = 0; i < circleSteps; i++)
        {
            var circleFraction = (float)i / circleSteps;
            var angleRadians = 2 * Mathf.PI * circleFraction;
            var x = circleRadius * Mathf.Cos(angleRadians);
            var y = circleRadius * Mathf.Sin(angleRadians);
            var coord = center + new Vector3(x, 0, y);

            var rotatedCoord = RotatePointAroundPivot(coord, center, velocity);

            GameObject sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
            sphere.transform.position = rotatedCoord;
            sphere.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = color;

        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        var centers = new List<Vector3>();
        centers.Add(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));

        int numCircles = 3;
        for (int i = 1; i <= numCircles; i++)
        {
            var center = new Vector3(10, 10, 10) + centers[i - 1];
            centers.Add(center);

            var velocity = center - centers[i - 1];
            DrawCircle(center, velocity);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well into the `velocity` you would pass a vector representing the rotation axis * angle ... For example if you want to rotate around the global Z axis about 90° this would be `new Vector3 (0,0,90)` 

Your issue is that you calculate that angle and axis wrong in `var velocity = center - centers[i - 1];` this will return a vector between two of your centers... Which will be `10,10,10` since your first center has `0,0,0` your second has `10,10,10` I guess what you actually want is circles that are perpendicular to that vector, right?

Comment: Yes hadn't thought of it that way, but yes the circles should be perpendicular to the vector between circle A and B

Comment: I'm still not sure how to achieve that though - I have no idea how to calculate a rotation that is perpendicular to the vector

Comment: I'd be interested to know why somebody downvoted this question?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you got that `RotateAroundPivot` method from threads like e.g. [this one](https://answers.unity.com/questions/532297/rotate-a-vector-around-a-certain-point.html) which uses angles as input.

Which is confusing for your use case.

What you have is an offset vector between the centers from

```
var velocity = center - centers[i - 1];
```

so instead of somehow calculate Euler angles from here you could/should rather directly use [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) which already calculates it for you

> Creates a rotation with the specified forward and upwards directions.
>
> Z axis will be aligned with forward, X axis aligned with cross product between forward and upwards, and Y axis aligned with cross product between Z and X.

This rotation you can then use in your calculation like

```
void RotateAroundPivot(Vector3 point, Vector3 pivot, Vector3 direction)
{
    var currentOffset = point - pivot;

    var newOffset = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction) * currentOffset;

    return pivot + newOffset;
}
```

---

*Note: typing on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*

*Not sure right now if this is it or you have to add 90° to it ^^*

---

After further thoughts it might not be that trivial actually ^^

I think what you would need is

0. You have the offset direction between your centers
1. Get the current offset vector
2. Get a perpendicular vector to these two -> that is the axis you are going to rotate around
3. Get the current angle between your current offset and the center direction
4. Get the difference between this current angle and 90° which is your target angle
5. Rotate about this difference angles around the perpendicular axis and you should have your position.

Something like maybe

```
void RotateAroundPivot (Vector3 point, Vector3 pivot, Vector3 centerOffset)
{
    // 1.
    var currentOffset = point - pivot;

    // 2.
    var rotationAxis = Vector3.Cross(currentOffset, centerOffset);

    // 3.
    var currentAngle = Vector3.Angle(currentOffset, centerOffset);

    // 4.
    var angleDistance = 90 - currentAngle;

    // 5.
    var rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angleDistance, rotationAxis);

    var newOffset = rotation * currentOffset;

    return pivot + newOffset;
}
```

*Still not sure though since smartphone ^^*

Comment: ah, that sounds ideal. I will give it a go tomorrow